# Riak, merkle tree, implementation

Tags: hash, tree, erlang, riak

Could somebody explain to me how merkle tree implementation works in riak-core, please?

https://github.com/basho/riak_core/blob/develop/src/merkerl.erl

I don't understand what is it offfset, for example.

Thanks!

Comment: And it seems the high of tree is bounden by 20 (Key is a 160b binary). Is it true?

Comment: The url seems to be invalid.

Comment: The code is now at https://github.com/basho/riak_core/blob/1.4/src/merkerl.erl .  The `develop` branch is now setup for Riak 2.0 development.

Answer (score 3):

The tree is both a K/V lookup tree and a Merkle tree in one, more or less. The tree is defined by looking at a 160 bit sha1 hash. The 160 bits gives 20 bytes. At the first level of the tree, we store up to 256 subtrees according to the 0th byte of the hash. At the next level, it is the 1st byte, then the 2nd and so on.

This is a called a digital tree scheme, where the digits in the hash encode the path to take in the tree. This allows us to replace data in the tree. Alternatively, look up the concept `trie`. At the same time, we sign each nodes kids with sha1 to track a change in the given subtree. When running to find the diff, we can thus ignore subtrees with the same signature as they must be equivalent by construction.

The value `offset` encodes how far in the 160 bit key we are currently. The `offset_key/1` function offsets to the right byte in the key to look at.